# Replicate an s3 replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am replicating some data from third party from my production env to test env which are in same region (but different AWS accounts). Can i re-replicate the replica to my Dev env once again (same AWS account) OR is there an efficient way to do it instead of s3-replication feature?

Comment: Did you try setting up S3 replication with the test bucket as source and the dev bucket as destination? What happened?

Comment: Yes i did, and i don't see any data replicating.